# ManagedBean functions not being called

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

I am trying to create a basic datatable which fetches the value from database and displays in the table format. However while I try to debug I see that managed bean functions are not being called. Below is the code

list.xhtml:

```xml
<h:body>
    <h3>Expense list</h3>


    <h:dataTable value="#{userMB.entries}" var="e" styleClass="table"
        headerClass="table-header" rowClasses="table-odd-row,table-even-row">

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Date</f:facet>
            #{e.date}
        </h:column>     
    </h:dataTable>
</h:body>
```

UserMB.java

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserMB {

    private List<Entry> entries;

    @EJB(mappedName = "entryServices")
    private EntryServices entryServices;

    public UserMB() {

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context
                .getExternalContext().getRequest();
        HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession(false);
        User user = (User) httpSession.getAttribute("user");
        entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        entries = entryServices.getEntryByUser(user);
    }

    public List<Entry> getEntries() {
        return entries;
    }

    public void setEntries(List<Entry> entries) {
        this.entries = entries;
    }

    public EntryServices getEntryServices() {
        return entryServices;
    }

    public void setEntryServices(
            EntryServices entryServices) {
        this.entryServices = entryServices;
    }

}
```

Comment: Whats `userMB.Entries`?

Comment: That was a typo when I copied it here, I have corrected it now in the question

Comment: If `init()` was not called, it means the associated managed-bean was not yet constructed. Have you verified the list is not empty ?

Comment: there is data in the database, but its not fetching as the function is not being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any error in the code or the facelet, sometimes I not choose the right package for the annotation that must be `javax.faces.ManagedBean` and `javax.faces.SessionScoped` otherwise the bean is never created.
In glassfish when I use a EJB in the ManagedBean it need to be serialized could you try this.
I hope this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is my problem.

Change the imports and works:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
```